# ASP controls with inline C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I'm using inline C# to write a dynamic drop down. Depending on if the user is logged in or not. I'd like to be able to write in some asp textbox's (see below). Is there a way to do this, or a better way of accomplishing the task.

Thanks.

```
<%
    if (checkLogin() == true)
    {
        Response.Write("<ul id=\"userDropdown\">");
        Response.Write("<li class=\"userDropdown_right\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"drop\">Test User</a>");
        Response.Write("<div class=\"dropdown align_right\" style=\"width:175px;\">");
        Response.Write("<div class=\"col_2\">");
        Response.Write("<h2>Test User</h2>");
        Response.Write("<h3>Administrator</h3>");
        Response.Write("<a href=\"#\">Settings </a>");
        Response.Write("<a href=\"#\">Logout </a>");
        Response.Write("</div></div></li></ul>");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<ul id=\"userDropdown\">"); 
        Response.Write("<li class=\"userDropdown_right\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"drop\">Login</a>");
        Response.Write("<div class=\"dropdown align_right\" style=\"width:175px;\">");
        Response.Write("<div class=\"col_2\">");

        **<asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" />**


        Response.Write("</div></div></li></ul>");
    }
%>
```

Comment: You can use a `PlaceHolder` control to direct the output to a specific place on the page rather than `Response.Write`.  Also, no, writing a server-side control to the page in this manner will not work (at least, it shouldn't, and if it does you shouldn't trust it).  I'll defer to the other suggestions already given for a better approach...

Comment: Create a custom control, and use LoginView control to display it if the user is logged in.

Comment: @Henk I'm using WebForms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a conditional like this:

```
<%
if (checkLogin()==true){
%> Logged In content here <%
} else { 
%>
Not Logged In content here, including server controls.
<% 
} 
%>
```

A templated control would also work.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?  The results from `Response.Write()` will be placed above the opening `<html>` tag.
So that's not a good idea.

You can use a Templated control, the LoginStatus control seems perfect for the job.

Answer (score 2):

@Tetsujin no Oni answer solves the problem, but...

Why don't you create your own user control (customDropDown.ascx) ???

By doing that you would be able to:

1. Reuse it elsewhere
2. Encapsulate the behavior, so you'll only need to make changes to one place
3. Don't work with strings and have intellisense support
4. Write HTML tags with support to visual studio preview

Comment: I agree, this html should be in a user control with its associated business logic in the controls code behind.

Comment: I can't see myself using this more than just in this one instance, or else creating a user control would be a good solution.